# ls | grep | rm -- How to format this command?

Tags: grep, ls, rm

I'm trying to delete a bunch of files in a certain directory (on Mac OS X using Terminal)

```
ls | grep \([1-9]\) | xargs rm
```

should do the trick, but it doesn't.  I'm trying to delete any file with a single digit in parentheses in the filename (duplicates downloaded from the web), but it ends up doing something like this:

```
> rm: 520syllabus2010: No such file or
> directory rm: (3).pdf: No such file or
> directory
```

because it doesn't interpret the space correct.  It should delete "520syllabus2010 (3).pdf"

What's the proper way of doing this?

Thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Your example filename doesn't contain a literal `#`.

Comment: @honk: He's not looking for a literal `#`.

Comment: Due to expansion by the shell, this will not work as expected if the cwd has a file named e.g. `(3)`. It's best to quote arguments so that the shell doesn't affect them.

Comment: You are being hit by The separator problem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs#The_separator_problem

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Short version:

```
rm *\([1-9]\)*
```

---

Do not pipe `ls` to `xargs`. Instead, pipe `find ... -print0` to `xargs -0`, in order to avoid such problems.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*([1-9])*' -print0 | xargs -0 rm
```

...which can be written as:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*([1-9])*' -exec rm {} \;
```

and:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*([1-9])*' -delete
```

which can further be shortened to just `rm` with a wildcard.

---

Normally, `ls` and `find` separate file names with newlines, but `xargs` splits its input by newline *or* space, resulting in the behavior you see.

It's possible tell `xargs` to split only by newline, but files *can* have newlines in their names too. In fact, on Linux and BSD, the *only* [disallowed character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) is the [*"null"* or zero byte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) – so it's what you should use in such cases.

In example 2 above, `-print0` tells `find` to separate filenames with a null byte; same for `xargs -0`. (A few other tools also have similar options, such as `sort -z` or `grep -zZ`.)

The "short version" uses a simple shell wildcard ("pattern" in [`bash` manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/darwin/reference/manpages/man1/bash.1.html) – see section "Pathname Expansion").

Comment: And just to be safe, it's better to use `*" "\\([1-9]\\).*` so that only files with a space before the paren'd number before the (a, to be fair) period are deleted.

Comment: Not very familiar with this syntax, but based on the upvotes I gave it a try and what do you know... it worked!  Thanks!

Comment: +1.  -print0 is essential for correct piping to xargs.